# Are there any Scala template engines other than scalate?

Tags: scala, template-engine, scalate

I'm tring to embed scalate in my website with sbt+jrebel, but found there are some problems I can't resolve.

So I want to know if there any other template engines based on scala?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about popping on the [Scalate group](http://groups.google.com/group/scalate) and describing the actual problems you're having? Am sure its fairly straight forward to work around? If the issue you're having is to do with sbt + jrebel and class reloading of scala code that you want to use inside your template engine; switching template engine's isn't sounding like an option (unless you want to stop using Scala in your templates). Plus Scalate is really the best and most popular template engine that uses Scala expressions inside it.

Comment: thank you very much. I have post some threads in scalate group before, but I'm not very good at scala(and the classloader of Java), that I can't find the reason.

Comment: you are right. Scalate is still the best one for me. PS: I have tried your jrebel plugin, but still not work with sbt. Finally, I decided to run without jrebel, just let jetty reload the webapp.

Comment: Scalate startup time could be improved, it takes several seconds just to initialize template engine. Also, with Scalate I get scala-compiler jar as a dependency.

Comment: It's seems like gitter group is abandoned, and google groups also. It's pity that scala doesn't have any simple template engine with good community... Twirl sucks because it's not supported in idea community edition

Answer (score 4):

Play framework for scala has a brand new scala template engine

not sure if it can be used outside of play

http://scala.playframework.org/documentation/scala-0.9.1/templates

Comment: [Twirl](https://github.com/spray/twirl) seems to allow this. (Not tried it though)

Comment: Since Play 2.3, [Twirl](https://github.com/playframework/twirl) has been split out of the Play project and can be used as a template engine in its own right.

Answer (score 3):

Pure Scala DSLs:

- [scala-xml](https://github.com/scala/scala-xml) (not sure how long this will be supported though)
- [ScalaTags](https://github.com/lihaoyi/scalatags)

"Regular" templating engines:

- [Twirl](https://github.com/playframework/twirl)
- JSP (Java)
- [Freemarker](https://github.com/freemarker/freemarker) (Java)
- [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) (Java)
- [Thymeleaf](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf) (Java)
- [Mustache.java](https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java) (Java)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to String Interpolation from Scala 2.10, now we can use native syntax to generated a complex text content.

Just use [Fastring](https://github.com/Atry/fastring). It has both good performance and simple usage.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on the JVM, Scala's interoperability with Java would let you use Velocity or Freemarker.

Comment: thank you, but I want templates base on scala, that I can run scala code in it

Answer (score 0):

I might want to look at [Stitchr](http://scala0.net/stitchr/)  which was largely inspired by StringTemplate

Comment: It's strange that it doesn't provide any demo about the template syntax in the website

Comment: It demos how to invoke the library, but where's the syntax of template?

Answer (score 0):

[Scalasti](http://software.clapper.org/scalasti/) is a Scala wrapper around StringTemplate.

Answer (score -1):

As already mentioned above, I would recommend using Twirl (the template system from Play). It's now very easy to use standalone. You'll have compile time checking of your templates and many more cool and simple stuff:

https://github.com/spray/twirl

Comment: A version maintained by the Play team is here:  https://github.com/playframework/twirl

Comment: A lot of people are using idea community with scala plugin. Are you suggesting to change IDE just for template editing?